# How to get name of arrays

Tags: android, arrays, resources

I have this array.xml

```
<resources>

    <string-array name="Abarth">
        <item name="id">1</item><item name="title">500</item>
        <item name="id">2</item><item name="title">Grande Punto</item>
        <item name="id">3</item><item name="title">Punto Evo</item>
        <item name="id">4</item><item name="title">500c</item>
        <item name="id">5</item><item name="title">695</item>
        <item name="id">6</item><item name="title">Punto</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="Alfa_Romeo">
        <item name="id">1</item><item name="title">155</item>
        <item name="id">2</item><item name="title">156</item>
        <item name="id">3</item><item name="title">159</item>
        <item name="id">4</item><item name="title">164</item>
        <item name="id">5</item><item name="title">145</item>
        <item name="id">6</item><item name="title">147</item>
        <item name="id">7</item><item name="title">146</item>
        <item name="id">8</item><item name="title">Gtv</item>
        <item name="id">9</item><item name="title">Spider</item>
        <item name="id">10</item><item name="title">166</item>
        <item name="id">11</item><item name="title">Gt</item>
        <item name="id">12</item><item name="title">Crosswagon</item>
        <item name="id">13</item><item name="title">Brera</item>
        <item name="id">14</item><item name="title">90</item>
        <item name="id">15</item><item name="title">75</item>
        <item name="id">16</item><item name="title">33</item>
        <item name="id">17</item><item name="title">Giulietta</item>
        <item name="id">18</item><item name="title">Sprint</item>
        <item name="id">19</item><item name="title">Mito</item>
    </string-array>

    <array name="marcas">
        <item>@array/Abarth</item>
        <item>@array/Alfa_Romeo</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

I want to get the content of the array marcas and the name of the subarrays, like "Abarth" or "Alfa_Romeo".

How can I do this? In other post I have read the next code, but it is for obtain the entire array, not only a part of the array.

```
Resources res = getResources();
        TypedArray ta = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.marcas);
        int n = ta.length();
        String[][] car = new String[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int id = ta.getResourceId(i, 0);
            if (id > 0) {
                car[i] = res.getStringArray(id);
            } else {
                // Error en el XML
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check my answer. i hope i understood question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the content of the array marcas and the name of the
>   subarrays, like "Abarth" or "Alfa_Romeo".

I don't know if i correctly understood your question but to obtain name of arrays you can use this:

```
TypedArray parent = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.marcas);
List<String> childs = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < parent.length(); i++) {
   int id = parent.getResourceId(i, 0);

   if (id > 0) {
      childs.add(getResources().getResourceEntryName(id));
   }
}

parent.recycle();
```

**Output:**

```
Abarth
Alfa_Romeo
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the best solution.

Another question please. If I touch on an element in my spinner, "Abarth" for example, how can I obtain the values only of this element in the array R.array.marcas?

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin You mean items in array Abarth? btw, if working, please accept answer to see that it works (for another people), thanks.

Comment: If I need now the values of some of this elements, like "Abarth" that is a <string-array name="Alfa_Romeo">, How can I obtain its elements?

Comment: You mean items that contains array Abarth?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the elements of "Abarth" inside "<string-array name="Abarth">" for example. Sorry, I had a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything well, To get the TypedArray resource name you need to use `getResourceEntryName`. Add the following code to get the [resourceEntryName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getResourceEntryName%28int%29), to get what you looking for.

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
```

This will give you the output "Abarth" and "Alfa_Romeo".

Comment: This is my answer ^^. I want to get the name of the arrays like "<string-array name="Alfa_Romeo">" to introduce later in a list.

Comment: @Yup what's new in your solution? Check the question properly.

Comment: Yes, it's shows me null, when I have "Abarth" and "Alfa_Romeo"